# 1:1 Python Request Response

Tags: python

I have a RESTful `API` call in which I pass a list of IDs, `x`, as a parameter. However, each value in the list may or may not have a corresponding record in the response, `y`. Thus, `length(x) >= length(y)`. I want my request and response to be `1:1`, so that for every value in `x` there exists some record in `y`. How can I handle when for some value in `x` there is no related record in `y`? Can I set a default value in the request for when the query is false? For example, currently `x = [1,2,3]` returns `y = [1,3]` when there is no record for `2`. I want the response to be `y = [1,None,3]`.

Please let me know if there is any other information you need me to provide.

views.py

```
def do_something(self, request):
    try:
        r = requests.get(
            self.URL + 'domain/endpoint in (' + request + ')',
            headers=self.Header)
        r.raise_for_status()
    except:
        print(r.text)
        raise
    return r.json()
```

```
y = obj.do_something(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, these will be handled either on the server side or the client side.
A get response will probably in the form of the JSON. JSON will certainly reflect the missing values and on the basis of that you can add a None while forming the list.

Comment: the `JSON` returned does not reflect when a key value does not have a related match. Only when there is a matching pair is `JSON` returned. How can I ensure there is a pair for every key value?

Comment: I have a base `API` call which I pull an `ID` for each record returned. Then I pass these `IDs` as a parameter in a second `API` call. This second call is where I am returning the data where for some `x` there is no related `y`.